# How to eliminate the gaps before and after \frac{}{}?

Tags: spacing, fractions

The macro `\frac` add a gap (approx 1.2pt) before and after the whole fraction. You could compare

```
\[\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\]
```

and

```
\newcommand{\mycmd}{\hskip1.2pt1\hskip1.2pt}
\[\mycmd\mycmd\mycmd\mycmd\mycmd\mycmd\mycmd\mycmd\]
```

Even, the `\genfrac` command (setting the third arguement to "0pt") has still keep the gaps back:

```
\newcommand{\myfrac}{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{1}{1}}
\[\myfrac\myfrac\myfrac\myfrac\myfrac\myfrac\myfrac\myfrac\]
```

though the horizontal rule is invisible.

The gaps takes some problems:

1. If we use a huge font (e.g. set `\fontsize` to 20pt), the numerator/denominator does not match the fractional line in the projecting.
2. If we write a binomial coefficient, the gaps are not necessity.

So, a customized command `\newfrac` without the gaps is beneficial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TeX has a concept of a generalized fraction with delimiters. In case of `\frac`, there is a rule but no delimiters. Then TeX surrounds the fraction by a space of `\nulldelimiterspace`. Default is 1.2 pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{0pt}
  \frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}
  \frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}\frac{1}{1}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Why `\setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{20pt}\binom{m}{n}\binom{m}{n}` or `\setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{20pt}\genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{m}{n}\genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{m}{n}`are invalid?

Comment: @nameabc: It is not invalid; `\nulldelimiterspace` is not used, because there are delimiters that are used instead.

Comment: It should be noted that TeX uses *one* value of `\nulldelimiterspace` per formula, so one cannot change it in the middle of a formula.

Comment: One can change it in the middle of the formula but the last value is used for all fractions.